# “Openness will be developed in [us/ourselves]” – which is correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, pronouns

I’m not sure which one is correct in this case:

> Openness will be developed in **ourselves** to our own Higher Self.
>
> Openness will be developed in **us** to our own Higher Self.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You will usually get a better answer if you elaborate what exactly you want to express and what you know so far (e.g., from dictionaries). Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Ourselves implies "each of us, individually".  "us" could mean us as individuals, **or** us as a group.  So, I'd say that "ourselves" is the better choice as as it's less ambiguous.

Obviously this assumes that you are talking about this process of "openness development" being done by individuals, rather than collectively as a group.

Comment: Thank you Max. I'm translating a course manual, so you're probably right, 'ourselves' would be more relevant in this case. ;-) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sentence, I think it's more clear this way:

The student will be more open to connect to one’s Higher Self.

Comment: Yes, your new sentence is better. But, this does not solve the question itself − which of the two sentences given by you is correct? Of course, your problem goes with you substituting the new sentence. But the  question remains: which of the two sentences given by you is correct?

Comment: That sentence is much, much worse. _One_ refers either to some unspecified, indistinct person (the generic person that is everyone and no one in particular) or formally and often humorously to oneself, and it makes no sense whatsoever for anyone but an identical subject to connect to that person’s Higher Self. You're basically saying that the student can connect to some unspecified person’s Higher Self (or to your own Higher Self), which is a very odd thing to say and very different from the original sentence.

Comment: That said, apart from the pronoun being wrong, this way of phrasing it does indeed sound much more natural. To bypass the pronoun issue entirely, simply use the plural (“Upon completing the course, students will be more open to connecting with their Higher Self”) or speak directly to the student (“The course will make you more open to connecting with your Higher Self”).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I like that, it also gets around the difficulty  of the plural 'students' and singular 'Higher Self'

Answer (score 0):

No native speaker would ever say either of those, as explained in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/354364/2085) and its references.

The closest valid possibility begins:

> Our openness to our own higher self will develop....

The ellipsis is because it still needs more in it to finish the sentence.