# passive voice in continuous tense

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, continuous-aspect

Could someone please tell me what the passive voice is for the following sentence:

> I was trying to study Chinese but I couldn't.

I think it will be:

> Chinese was being tried to be studied, but it wasn't possible.

But I'm not sure, I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generate a grammatical solution to this puzzle for reasons elaborated in linguist Geoffery Pullum’s 2014 paper [Fear and Loathing of the English Passive](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/passive_loathing.pdf) published in *Language and Communication*.

Specifically, your suggestion violates the rule that Pullum provides in **Information-structure constraints on passives** under section 2.4.2:

> The denotation of the *by*-phrase NP in a passive clause must denote something at least as new in the discourse as the subject.

That’s because the proffered reformulation (with missing *by me* added) is ungrammatical in English:

> ***Chinese** was being tried to be studied **by me**, ...

The reason that that is ungrammatical is because the subject *Chinese* cannot be used because it is newer in the discourse than the passive complement *by me*. Pullum writes:

> This information-packaging constraint is a real, important, and fully general part of the way long passives work.

I recommend reading the whole paper, but if you prefer something like a shorter, *Cliff Notes* version of that paper, you can read [a 2011 précis of his related work](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922).

Comment: Let's finish that quote, shall we? *It is remarkable that ... hardly any attempts at describing the passive make any mention of it* [i.e., the constraint mentioned]. Not really so remarkable because to buy the premise, you have to buy that the following is ungrammatical: *A man walks into a pub leading a bear on a leash. #A beer and a pot of honey are ordered by him.*

Comment: @deadrat That sentence is being considered grammatical by you?

Comment: I find *A beer and a pot of honey are ordered by him* to be unremarkable narrative. The trouble with the OP's sentence is that the direct object isn't *Chinese*; it's *to study Chinese*. If the OP's sentence had been *I attempted Chinese* (to avoid the alternate meaning of *try*), the passive is easy: *Chinese was attempted by me*. The infinitive doesn't quite sound idiomatic: *To study Chinese was attempted by me*, but *Studying Chinese was attempted by me* seems OK.

Comment: @deadrat Native speakers generate *Chinese was attempted by me* then? I disagree.

Comment: Couldn't you use something like, "Study of Chinese was attempted with little success."?

Comment: No, of course not, because native speakers don't say *I attempted Chinese*. (They would say *I studied Chinese* and (more awkwardly) Chinese was studied by me.) They would say *The Wright brothers attempted manned flight*, which has a passive transformation. The problem is that the infinitive clause object in the active voice doesn't transpose easily to the subject in the passive voice.  The gerund or an equivalent noun (as suggested by @sshanky) is preferred. I'm skeptical that it has anything to do with the novelty of beer and honey.

Comment: *I attempted Chinese but gave up* sounds fine to me, FWIW @deadrat

Comment: Chinese was what was trying to be studied but couldn't be. But I don't like it because it diminishes the conflict between *trying to study* and *not being able to*, which seems like an unlikely thing to want to do.