# Passive structure with gerund

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, gerunds

I was asked to convert the following active sentence into passive:

> I admit taking the money without permission from his mom.

My first suggestion was:

> It is admitted that the money has been taken without permission from his mom.

However, the person requesting asked me to use a gerund structure, so I came up with the following sentence I'm not happy about:

> The money is admitted being taken without permission from his mom.

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Your examples are okay if you're forced into distorting the original. However, you don't have to switch all verbs, only the main verb, *admit*. Might need to say the admission was done by you, or is it you'm? But that's awful.

Comment: 'The money is admitted being taken (by myself) ...' sounds like nothing a normal English-speaking person would say. Some 'advanced' test questions on the English language require unnatural sentences as answers.

Comment: Marco: please allow me. **Passives are created with active (action) verbs**. The verb **admit** won't work for that. I stole the money. The money was stolen by me. Yeah? The hospital admits patients every day. Patients are admitted to the hospital every day. BUT:  Taking the money without permission from his mom was admitted by me. **would be a very hard sell**.

Comment: The true passive equivalent would be the unnatural and ungrammatical *The money being taken without permission from his mom is admitted (by me) The problem is that in the active version _taking the money without permission from his mom_ is a subordinate complement clause, and it's not normally possible to passive such embedded clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, whoever asked you to convert the sentence into passive appears not to be aware of much English grammar. The quoted sentence has two verbs, thus two clauses, with the same subject, but not the same object. Each clause can be converted into passive, as it happens, since they are both transitive, but one is the object of the other.

In general, complex sentences cannot be converted as a whole from active to passive, because there's more than one verb involved. Transitivity -- and therefore Passive, which is a function of transitivity -- applies to clauses, not verbs or sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The direct object in your sentence is the gerund phrase *taking the money without permission from his mom*.

That is what you will move to the subject position to create a passive construction:

> **Active**: *I admit taking the money without permission from his mom.*
>
> **Passive**: *Taking the money without permission from his mom is admitted
> [by me].*

Comment: Yes, that would be the passive and truly awkward.

Comment: I'd say that _taking the money without permission from his mom_ is not object but catenative complement of "admit". Clauses can't function as objects; only NPs can do that. The only object in the sentence is "the money", and since it is located in a subordinate clause passivisation becomes impossible. The true passive is the unnatural and ungrammatical *_The money being taken without permission from his mom is admitted (by me)_.

Comment: @BillJ: Whatever you call *taking the money* (and traditional grammars do call it an object), it's in the subject position in the passive, functioning like a noun. And *taking* is no doubt what I would call a gerund and what you would, I believe, call a gerund-participle.

Comment: To say that clauses can be direct objects makes little sense, which is why trad grammar is wrong about this, and has been proved to be so. In very simple terms, a catenative clause is nothing like an object, but is a distinct non-finite clause such that the _admit_ clause cannot satisfactorily be regarded as containing an object.

Comment: @BillJ: Whatever it is, it can be moved from its place to the subject position to create a passive construction.

Comment: Yes, but the result is neither grammatical nor the passive of the original.

Comment: @BillJ: The main clause is in the passive voice, and the sentence — though awkward — is grammatical.

Comment: No,@BillJ is right: what you have labelled as the passive transform is [not grammatical](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/354364/2085) in English.

Comment: @tchrist: Are you saying that the active *I admit taking money* rendered in the passive as *Taking money is admitted* is grammatically incorrect? I disagree. **Q**: *What happens during interrogation?* **A**: *Crimes are confessed. Taking money is admitted...*

Comment: "Taking money is admitted to by no one" is not grammatical because it hasn't already appeared.

Comment: @tchrist: How did the *to* in *admitted **to*** get introduced here? And are you making a distinction between *Taking money is admitted* and *Taking money is admitted by no one*? In any case, this whole business of not-having-already-appeared is not understood [by the speakers of the language].

Comment: @tchrist: I read the paper. From what I can tell, Pullum would find only A2 objectionable in this discourse: **Q**: *What could happen during the interrogation?* **A1**: *Taking the money is admitted.* **A2**: *Taking the money is admitted by me.* **A3**: *Taking the money is admitted by Bob.* **A4**: *Taking the money is admitted by me. Taking the car is admitted by Bob.* **//** But outside the context of discourse (and there is none in the OP’s question), *Taking the money is admitted by me* is correct, as evidenced in A4.

Answer (score 1):

Your re-written example is not correct. The structure of the original is as follows:

Main Clause:

> I [subject(NP)]
>
> admit [predicator(V)]
>
> taking the money without permission from his mom. [complement(GPC)]

Subordinate Clause:

> taking [predicator(V)]
>
> the money [complement(Object-NP)]
>
> without permission from his mom [adjunct(PP)]

Passivization involves an object in an active clause appearing in subject position in a related passive.

> I kept **him**. -> **He** was kept. [object NP]

Objects (which are always noun phrases) are to be differentiated from other possible complements.

> I kept **to it**. -> ***To it** was kept. [prepositional phrase]
>
> I tried **to take it**. -> ***To take it** was tried. [*to*-infinitival]
>
> I helped **take it**. -> ***Take it** was helped. [plain infinitival]

Though their distribution overlaps heavily with that of noun phrases, gerund-participials cannot generally be passivized, and when they can, the result is almost always awkward at best.

> I kept **taking it**. -> ***Taking it** was kept. [gerund-participial]
>
> We tried asking nicely. -> ?**Asking nicely** was tried already.

The exception seems to be when the past-participle in the passive doubles as an adjective. But then the clause is probably better analyzed as a complex-intransitive construction rather than a passive.

> Carrying weapons is (remains) forbidden.

With that said, the only clause you could passivize would be the subordinate clause *taking the money without permission from his mom*. This would seem to require the addition of *to*, and turns out a little awkward.

> I admit (to) *the money being taken without permission from his mom*.

Alternatively, you could use a GPC as a supplement to get a passive:

> The money being taken without permission from his mom, that was admitted.

Or, you could try a pseudo-cleft:

> What was admitted was the money being taken without permission from
> his mom.

They all seem a bit awkward really.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the sentence in active voice.

Anyway, I am trying to make it passive.

passive: The money is admitted to having been taken by him without permission from his mom.

Comment: Three hits on Google for "the money is admitted to" (and zero for "the money is admitted to having been"). 636 000 for "admitted to taking the money". This is heading towards needing to label the former as unacceptable through unidiomaticity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the problem is that non-native-speakers of English, drilled with "fake rules" about passivization that do not generate grammatical results, have no internal check that would allow them to [reject these abominations](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/354364/2085) on their own.

Comment: @tchrist And the older one gets, the more one feels the need of a way to check these internal checks. Good answer over there.

Answer (score -1):

The structure of the sentence is fine. We can see that if we replace the past participle "admitted" with the past participle "seen":

> The money is seen being taken without permission from his mom.

However, while money can certainly be "seen", I don't think that money can be "admitted". I'd therefore say that your sentence does not work; the meaning doesn't make sense.

Note that the original sentence already contains a gerund: "taking". Keep that nominal phrase the same ("taking the money without permission from his mom") and use it as the subject of a sentence in the passive voice. I think that you'll get a solution that way.

Comment: That presupposes that _taking the money without permission from his mom_ is the object of admit. But objects consist of NPs, not clauses, so the _ing_ clause can't be object in the active, and hence it can't be subject of the passive version. The only object in the sentence is the NP "the money", so the passive is the unnatural and ungrammatical *_The money being taken without permission from his mom is admitted (by me)_.

Comment: @BillJ I wrote the word “clause” by accident. Fixed.